# How to find day of week for Intended day

Tags: java, android, calendar

i don't know how can i find a day of week which i want?

for example :

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
String s="2019-10-07";
        try {
            calendar.setTime(simpleDateFormat.parse(s));
            if(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK == 2){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Mo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but it does not work correct! current day of calendar just Considered, not my specified day.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends like `Calendar`, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: With java.time it’s also a bit simpler and quite somewhat clearer: you just need `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s);` and then `if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))` (the if condition evaluates to `true`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) is a constant `7` so it's working correctly, just not how you expected. You should not be using `Calendar` in new code (instead use the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)). But [`calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) will give you the value you seek.